# Angular 4 <router-outlet> breaking page layout

Tags: angular, zurb-foundation, angular-routing

I started an Angular 4 application using Zurb Foundation as CSS framework and everything was looking/behaving fine until I had to use the Router to provide navigation to the app. For better understanding, here's a visual representation of the layout:

[image: App layout]

And this is the HTML markup, using Foundation CSS:

```
<div class="grid-y medium-grid-frame" #application>    <!-- (1) Main content grid -->
  <div class="cell shrink header">    <!-- (1.1) HEADER-->
    <!-- MENUBAR -->
  </div>

  <div class="cell medium-auto medium-cell-block-container">    <!-- (1.2) WEB MAIN CONTENT SECTION -->

    <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x">
      <div class="cell medium-2 medium-cell-block padding-top-1" data-sticky-container>    <!-- (1.2.1) LEFT SIDEBAR -->

        <!-- INDEPENDENTLY SCROLLABLE LEFT SIDEBAR -->
      </div>

      <div class="cell medium-10 medium-cell-block padding-top-1">  <!-- (1.2.2) MAIN CONTENT -->

        <!-- INDEPENDENTLY SCROLLABLE MAIN DIV -->

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- (1.3) BOTTOM PANEL -->
  <div class="cell medium-3 footer">

    <!-- OBJECT INFO -->

  </div>

</div>
```

After adding the navigation, I had to move some code inside components, and now the app template looks like this:

```
<div class="grid-y medium-grid-frame" #application>    <!-- (1) Main content grid -->

  <router-outlet>  <!-- APP MAIN ROUTER -->
    (1.1) HEADER

    <router-outlet>  <!-- SECONDARY OUTLET, TO LOAD THE COMPONENT SELECTED IN THE MENU BAR -->
      (1.2) WEB MAIN CONTENT SECTION

      (1.3) BOTTOM PANEL
    </router-outlet>

  </router-outlet>

</div>
```

The app loads the components correctly, but the left sidebar and main content are not scrollable anymore, and the bottom panel is missing, so the app is unusable. Could it be because the `<router-outlet>` tag makes that the CSS classes are not applied correctly?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

My guess at the issue is that Angular is mixing up the `router-outlet`'s.

I suggest adding a name first and foremost, so you and Angular can differentiate between the outlets, like so:

route config:

```
{path: 'main', component: MainComponent, outlet: 'app-main'}
```

and the outlet

```
`<router-outlet name='app-main'></router-outlet>
```

Same goes for your other outlet.

Try this and see if it works.

Comment: Hi, I tried naming the secondary outlet but it didn't make any difference. Anyway, I'm doing some tests because if I name both outlets, the app always redirects me to the homepage, so perhaps I have something wrong in the routes. I'll post the results ASAP, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You Need to use Named Router outlet, in case you are trying to attach more than one outlet, and then provide name of router as outlet in router configuration

```
<b>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>   
  <router-outlet name="example"></router-outlet>
</b>

[
    {
        path: 'route',
        component: ExampleComponent,
        outlet: 'example'
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is because adding `<router-outlet>` makes that some styles are not applied. Here you can see the DOM of the app before and after using the router:

[image: DOM before and after using router-outlet]

And here the applied CSS to the DIV `<div class="cell medium-auto medium-cell-block-container>... </div>`:

**NOTE: I swapped BEFORE and AFTER, sorry!**
[image: CSS]
As you can see, there are a couple of CSS rules that aren't applied because they use the `>` CSS selector, which applies only to direct descendants. The same happens with more divs deeper in the hierarchy.

Will I have to add custom CSS to fix this issue?